# How to change image of child component button and navigate from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component which is called `<TopBar>` which will be included in other components.
The goal is when I click on any items on `<TopBar/>` (redirect to other pages), it should update `state` and navigate to the new page.

Child:

```
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
// const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;


class TopBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            profile: require('../../img/profile.png'),
            mail: require('../../img/mail_icon.png'),
            setting: require('../../img/settings.png'),
            notification: require('../../img/notification.png'),
            logout: require('../../img/logout.png'),
            home: require('../../img/home.png')
        }
    }


    onchangeLinkName = (no) => {
        if (no === 1)
            this.setState({
                home: require('../../img/home.png')
            });
        else if (no === 2)
            this.setState({
                mail: require('../../img/mail_icon_2.png')
            });
        else if (no === 3)
            this.setState({
                notification: require('../../img/notification_2.png')
            });
        else if (no === 4)
            this.setState({
                profile: require('../../img/profile_2.png')
            });
        else if (no === 5)
            this.setState({
                logout: require('../../img/logout.png')
            });
    }

    home_pressin = () => {
        this.setState({
            home: require('../../img/home.png')
        });
    }
    home_pressout = () => {
        this.setState({
            home: require('../../img/home_2.png')
        });
    }
    logout_pressin = () => {
        this.setState({
            logout: require('../../img/logout.png')
        });
    }
    logout_pressout = () => {
        this.setState({
            logout: require('../../img/logout_2.png')
        });
    }
    notification_pressin = () => {
        this.setState({
            notification: require('../../img/notification_2.png')
        });
    }
    notification_pressout = () => {
        this.setState({
            notification: require('../../img/notification.png')
        });
    }
    setting_pressin = () => {
        this.setState({
            setting: require('../../img/settings_2.png')
        });
    }
    setting_pressout = () => {
        this.setState({
            setting: require('../../img/settings.png')
        });
    }
    profile_pressin = () => {
        this.setState({
            profile: require('../../img/profile_2.png')
        });
    }
    profile_pressout = () => {
        this.setState({
            profile: require('../../img/profile.png')
        });
    }

    mail_pressin = () => {
        this.setState({
            mail: require('../../img/mail_icon_2.png')
        });
    }
    mail_pressout = () => {
        this.setState({
            mail: require('../../img/mail_icon.png')
        });
    }

    tonotification = () => {
        //  navigate('page3')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('notification');
    }

    tomail = () => {
        //  navigate('page3')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('mail');
    }

    toprofile = () => {
        //  navigate('page3')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('profile');
    }
    tohome = () => {
        //  navigate('page3')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{});
        // this.setState({
        //     // home: require('../../img/mail_icon.png')
        // });
    }
    tosignin = () => {
        //  navigate('page3')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
    }
    _changeStyle() {
        //var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        //var backgroundColor = backgroundcolors[Math.floor(Math.random()*backgroundcolors.length)];
        this.setState({

        })
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <View>
                <ImageBackground source={require('../../img/blue_bar_for_every_screen.png')}
                    style={styles.foregroundImage} >
                    <View style={{ marginTop: 15, padding: 10, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
                        <View style={{}}>
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.tohome} onPressIn={this.home_pressin} onPressOut={this.home_pressout}>
                                <Image
                                    style={styles.button_header}
                                    source={this.state.home}
                                />
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{}}>
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.tomail} onPressIn={this.mail_pressin} onPressOut={this.mail_pressout}>
                                <Image
                                    style={styles.button_header}
                                    source={this.state.mail}
                                />
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View>
                        {/* <View style={{}}>
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={this.setting_pressin} onPressOut={this.setting_pressout}>
                                <Image
                                    style={styles.button_header}
                                    source={this.state.setting}
                                />
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View> */}
                        <View style={{}}>
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.tonotification} onPressIn={this.notification_pressin} onPressOut={this.notification_pressout}>
                                <Image
                                    style={styles.button_header}
                                    source={this.state.notification}
                                />
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{}}>
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.toprofile} onPressIn={this.profile_pressin} onPressOut={this.profile_pressout}>
                                <Image
                                    style={styles.button_header}
                                    source={this.state.profile}
                                />
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{}}>
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.tosignin} onPressIn={this.logout_pressin} onPressOut={this.logout_pressout}>
                                <Image
                                    style={styles.button_header}
                                    source={this.state.logout}
                                />
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Parent:

```
export default class Notification extends Component {


    _changeStyle() {
        //var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        //var backgroundColor = backgroundcolors[Math.floor(Math.random()*backgroundcolors.length)];
        this.setState({

        })
    }

    render() {
        const username = "";
        const password = "";


        return (
            <ImageBackground source={require('../../img/img_login_back.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
                <View style={{}}>
                    <TopBar>

                        {/* {this.props.Notification.spilit(' ').map((word))} */}
                        {/* <DefaultRenderer
                            navigationState={this.props.children[0]}
                            onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate}
                        /> */}
                        {/* {React.createElement(this.props.children[0].component, {key: "you can pass props here"})} */}
                    </TopBar>
                    <View style={{justifyContent:'center',marginTop:100}}>
                        <Text style={{ position: 'absolute', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Verdana' }}>
                            No Design Provided For Notification
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood the problem... is that it doesn't navigate? Or what? Then, looking at your code, it seems that you should have a proper component to save a loooot of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am following correctly, it sounds like you want to do something like what I demonstrated in the following snippet.

In this example, state is managed in the parent, which maintains the current "item", which would be the page you want to navigate to.  This is passed down to the child component in the form of child property `currentItem`.

At the same time, I am passing the parent's `changeItem` method, which allows the child to change this value in the parent's state.

Finally, there is logic in the child to see if it's respective item matches the parent's currently selected item, so that the child can have different behavior based on what is selected.  Notice that no child state is required in this example.  All necessary data is captured by way of properties passed into the child.

This may not be quite exactly what you are trying to do, but I think it probably gets close enough to explaining how you can sync up your state/props between your parent and children components...?

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { item: 1 };
    }

    changeItem = newItem => {
        this.setState({ item: newItem });
    };

    render() {
        const { item } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>
                    Parent -{" "}
                    <code>
                        Item=[
                        {item}]
                    </code>
                </h2>
                <h4>Separate Children</h4>
                <SeparateChild currentItem={item} childItem={1} changeItem={this.changeItem} />
                <SeparateChild currentItem={item} childItem={2} changeItem={this.changeItem} />
                <SeparateChild currentItem={item} childItem={3} changeItem={this.changeItem} />
                <h4>One Child</h4>
                <OneChild currentItem={item} changeItem={this.changeItem} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SeparateChild extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { childItem, currentItem, changeItem } = this.props;
        return (
            <input
                type="button"
                style={{ marginRight: "5px", textAlign: "left", width: "200px" }}
                onClick={() => changeItem(childItem)}
                value={`Child - change to [${childItem}]${childItem === currentItem ? " [ACTIVE]" : ""}`}
            />
        );
    }
}

class OneChild extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { currentItem, changeItem } = this.props;
        const childItems = [1, 2, 3];
        return (
            <div>
                {childItems.map(childItem => {
                    return (
                        <input
                            type="button"
                            style={{ marginRight: "5px", textAlign: "left", width: "200px" }}
                            onClick={() => changeItem(childItem)}
                            value={`Child - change to [${childItem}]${childItem === currentItem ? " [ACTIVE]" : ""}`}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**POST EDITED:** I modified the snippet to demonstrate managing the children properties by way of the original separate components or same behavior handled in a single component.

Comment: problem is what if you have multiple button in child component then how will you pass states from parent then ? 
or i should have only single button in a child component ?

Comment: Hi, @Shaiikh.  I modified my snippet to demonstrate the same behavior in either a single child component or separate children.  In either case, I passed state from the parent via the child component properties and did not need to manage child state in this example.  You could maintain a single child component, instead, if that makes sense for your usage.  Does this help?